# How to change win10 taskbar text color from BLACK to WHITE?

Tags: windows-10, taskbar, colors

I've upgraded to win10 from win7, and find the texts on the taskbar are black, which make them hard to read:

[image]

I know how to change the color of the taskbar(and titlebar etc.) following this post:http://www.intowindows.com/how-to-change-taskbar-color-in-windows-10/, yet now I'm asking if there is a way to change the color of the ***texts*** to **WHITE**.

Thx in advance~

Comment: concerning the clock, there is an awesome open source fix (don't forget to star the guy to thanks him). https://github.com/White-Tiger/T-Clock/releases

Answer (score 9):

I figured out how to change the taskbar text to white, which is what I came here hoping to find.

Go to personalization in the control panel and switch to the default theme called Windows. The text will be white. Then switch the background and color back to whatever they were before, and the text should stay white.

Comment: Theme sounds might also have to be selected again after doing that.

Comment: I noticed this problem after updating to Windows 10 Fall Creators Update, although I can't be sure it wasn't there before the update, as I hadn't switched my taskbar icon sizes in sometime. Changing the sizes is what seemed to trigger the task tray text to be black. Fortunately, after trying a variety of potential fixes, your tip of changing the theme worked great.

Comment: thanks, this worked. The right theme name for windows 11 is "Windows (dark)", the second one. That one changes the foreground color to white.

Answer (score 3):

Please try the following.

```
reg.exe add "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\ThemeManager" /v "DllName" /t REG_EXPAND_SZ /d ^%SystemRoot^%\Resources\Themes\aero\aero.msstyles /f
```

Then sign off and on again.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to SuperUser! Can you [edit your answer](https://superuser.com/posts/1408113/edit) to add more information about why and how it works, in order to help people with a similar but different problem? Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The `.theme` edit achieved white text AND retained my other personalisations. Thank you Cees Timmerman!

To help non-super users step through Cees Timmermans's instructions:

To see the `Appdata` folder, go to your File Explorer options and set Hidden items to visible.

When you find your `.theme` then right-click, Open with > Notepad.

Scroll down to the `[VisualStyles]` section.

Find this line of original code:
`Path=%SystemRoot%\resources\themes\Aero\AeroLite.msstyles`

Copy in both lines of Cees' code over the top of that line of original code.

The result will be two rows of new code instead of the original one.

Don't delete other code in the `[VisualStyles]` section. Yours may be different, but in my `.theme` was:

```
ColorStyle=NormalColor

Size=NormalSize

AutoColorization=0

ColorizationColor=0XC466152C

VisualStyleVersion=10
```

Hit save in Notepad and close.

Follow Cees' instructions from point 3.

That's what worked for me.

Comment: Welcome to SuperUser. If you feel like you have anything to add to an existing answer, please gather enough reputation points to make edits on existing answers. Also, please review the help center for information how posts should be formatted.

Comment: @mtak, your comment is not helpful.  "Gathering" reputation points is not as simple as you make it out to be.  Editing should not require so much reputation points anyway, the edit can simply be vetted by the author.  This is a problem with SO, not with Daniel Spencer's answer.

Also, this new answer is different enough that it warrants a new one anyway.

Comment: @jdk1.0 Commenting more than two years later is also not particularly helpful ;) If you don't agree with the thresholds set, you can post on https://meta.superuser.com/ . As to whether it's easy to gather rep, that's relative and a matter of opinion.

Answer (score 0):

1. Rightclick your desktop and choose "Personalize", then save your theme.
2. Open `C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\Themes\THEMENAME.theme` in Notepad and change the `VisualStyles` section:

   ```
   [VisualStyles]
   ; black taskbar text: Path=%SystemRoot%\resources\themes\Aero\AeroLite.msstyles
   Path=%SystemRoot%\resources\themes\Aero\Aero.msstyles
   ```

   Normal Aero uses shading instead of colored window borders like AeroLite, but i didn't notice a difference in performance, maybe 100 MB more used RAM.
3. To load that change, select a different theme, and then your modified theme.

Comment: step 1 doesnt say how to save theme

Comment: Downvoted for really poor instructions . step 2 is ambiguous at best. Please edit your answer to include 'open with text editor' for step 2 and instructions on how to save theme in step 1

Comment: @KalamalkaKid 1. "Press the Save Theme button". 2. To edit a file's text, use a text editor. HTH.

Answer (score 0):

FOR SURE, this is a correct answer if this is particular scenario applies to to you.  Like me, you probably started out having the default Theme in place: "Widows" and decided you wanted to try some customizations.  Maybe you clicked on the Theme name: "Widows (Light)"  or another theme to see what it looked like.  One difference between the "Windows" theme and "Windows (Light)" theme is that the "Windows" theme has a white font for programs in the taskbar whereas the "Windows (Light) has a black font.

IN SUMMARY.  If you don't have a lot of customizations, choose the "Windows" theme and redo your customizations and you will have the white font.

Answer (score 0):

There's actually a really easy solution to this problem.

1. Navigate to Settings -> Personalization -> Colors
2. Under "choose your color", select "Custom"
3. Then you will see two options for colors, and under "default app mode", select "white"

   [Image shown here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IBZ6P.png)

*Note - this will also change the background color of apps